# Push notifications to Mi Band 3

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-low-energy, android, xiaomi-mi

How can I push notifications to my Mi Band 3 without notifications showing up on my phone?

It could be code, or could be an app for Windows or Android. 
I'm planning on writing an app using custom API; I want to decide the platform based on the software/API to push notifications to the band.
Note: I'm aware the PC would need to be in close proximity, and so on; they are redundant.

Currently, when paired, notifications show up on the Band whenever the Phone gets a notification(which is visible in the phone UI). 
My requirement is that the notification should not show up on my phone UI, only the band; currently, if I prevent a notification from being visible in the phone (banner lockscreen, pull-down tab), it does not get pushed to the Band either.

Comment: "`How can I push notifications to my Mi Band 3 without notifications showing up on my phone?`" ... personally, I would be happy to know "`How can I push notifications to my Mi Band 3?`", and could live with "`notifications showing up on my phone`" (or just not pair the band). Do you know how? If so, can you share?

Comment: Are you asking, or do you want me to change the question?

Comment: I am asking. Your question is your question. I should probably ask my own. ***BUT***, if you can post a URL here, I would be very, very grateful :-)

Comment: @mawg You can push any notification that pops up on your phone to your band using the Mi Fit app: just enable that app(from which notifications come from) on the Mi Fit app(which pushes it to the band). 
https://support.amazfit.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001983174-How-to-set-up-App-Notifications-in-Mi-Fit-app-

Comment: @Mawg If you want to take it a step further and be creative, please do look at:
https://www.greenbot.com/article/3157040/a-beginners-guide-to-ifttt-on-android.html to send custom notifications based on triggers, and https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/build-notification if you're building your own app! :)

Comment: Thanks a 1,000,000 I wish I could upvote you more. I think that you are going to make good contributions around here  :-)